# HttpWebRequest Cookies not being set

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I'm trying to do some simple stuff, I've already looked at the examples through the web and I'm not sure of what I'm doing wrong
It's a unit test that i'm doing to test some functionality that later will be performed by some different devices
Basically I'm creating a webrequest to my site, which returns a set of cookies, which we later on need
Then I want to create a new webrequest, using the returned cookies from the first response, but when i'm reading that info, the cookies are empty

```
var request =   (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/bla");
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.Method = "GET";

request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
request.CookieContainer.Add(originalResponse.Cookies); // originalResponse.Cookies has several cookies needed by "bla"
var response = request.GetResponse();
```

In another place... (inside "bla")

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies  // this is empty
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, found what was happening
THe problem's that we can't just set the cookiecontainer to have the cookies from the response, since it's a new request we need to set the domain that the cookies belong to as well (.net is not assuming that the domain is the one from the URI in the Request object)

so, we need to do something like this when setting the cookies :

```
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
request.CookieContainer.Add(new Uri("http://localhost"), originalResponse.Cookies);
```

Just as another note, i was having a Path problem when setting the cookies.. getting an error like "The 'Path'=/MyApp part of the cookie is invalid". I solved this by setting the cookies' path to nothing before adding them (and making them valid in the whole domain)

```
   for (int i = 0; i < originalResponse.Cookies.Count; i++)
   {
        originalResponse.Cookies[i].Path = String.Empty;
   }
```

Comment: If this solved the problem, mark it as solved so that others can find it easier and so that it is not listed as unanswered :)

Comment: how can i mark it as solved?? i tried to accept my own answer but it says that i need to wait for 2 days

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking at the request headers directly or even tried using HTTP inspection tools?

Is `originalResponse.Cookies` populated with data? Is the domain the same for the collection and the outgoing request?

Comment: i'm trying to use fiddler right now to see what's happening. however for some reason, fiddler doesn't capture the request (because it goes directly to iis). trying to solve that :)
the domain is the same, the originalResponse.Cookies is populated (it's in the code comment)

Comment: ok, the cookies are NOT being set in the request. however, the CookieContainer variable DOES HAVE the cookies. any ideas?

Comment: fiddler probably can't intercept because it has to act as a proxy and there's no proxy setup involved - are you saying that your new outbound request doesn't have any cookie data attached? Hmmm...

Comment: @annakata You can use this statement webRequest.Proxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1", 8888); to have fiddler intercept. May be it will help someone else.